# Splice and Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an issue with Splice and I don't think I am understanding this correctly. Let's say, I have an array of 17 items. I am using the Splice function to split this up into two arrays.

`let splicedItems = items.splice(0, 7);`

If I have items `0-17` this should remove items `0-6` (7 Items)

Then, I have a button on a menu for next and this should then splice again, however it's not. I know the next button is passing all information and my array length is 10 when being fetched in the next page of items.

I am calling this first part of the code, sending it out to then be recalled and show the next list of items. The first section is working fine and displaying 7 items. However, I have 10 items left and I am not able to split the code and my menu's not being shown.

```
export function showPlayerInventory(itemJson: string){
mp.gui.chat.push("showpinv");
ContextMenu.DrawMenu.Reset();

ToggleCursor(true);

let items: Interfaces.GameItem[] = JSON.parse(itemJson);
invMenuItems = items;

let cursorpos = mp.gui.cursor.position;

if(!Array.isArray(items)){
    return;
}

items.sort();

if(items.length > 7)
{
    let splicedItems = items.splice(0, 7);
    invMenuItems = items;
    let nextJson = JSON.stringify(items);

    splicedItems.forEach((value, index, array) => {
        if (value == null)
            return;

            if(value.Quantity > 1){
                ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption(`${value.Name} (${value.Quantity})`, ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", value]);
            }
            else{
                ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption(`${value.Name}`, ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", value]);
            }
    });

    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption("Next", ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", "next", items]);

    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption("Exit", ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", "exit"]);

    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.Ready(true, cursorpos);
    return;
}
else
{
    items.forEach((value, index, array) => {
        if (value == null)
            return;

            if(value.Quantity > 1){
                ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption(`${value.Name} (${value.Quantity})`, ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", value]);
            }
            else{
                ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption(`${value.Name}`, ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", value]);
            }
    });
    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption("Exit", ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", "exit"]);

    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.Ready(true, cursorpos);
    return;
}
return;
}
```

Second section

```
export function showNextInventory(items: Interfaces.GameItem[]){
mp.gui.chat.push("showninv");
ContextMenu.DrawMenu.Reset();

ToggleCursor(true);

let cursorpos = mp.gui.cursor.position;

if(!Array.isArray(items)){
    return;
}

mp.gui.chat.push(items.length.toString());

items = invMenuItems;

if(items.length > 7)
{
    let splicedItems = items.splice(0, 7);
    invMenuItems = items;
    splicedItems.forEach((value, index, array) => {
        if (value == null)
            return;

            if(value.Quantity > 1){
                ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption(`${value.Name} (${value.Quantity})`, ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", value]);
            }
            else{
                ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption(`${value.Name}`, ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", value]);
            }
    });

    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption("Next", ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", "next", items]);

    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption("Exit", ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", "exit"]);

    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.Ready(true, cursorpos);
    return;
}
else
{
    items.forEach((value, index, array) => {
        if (value == null)
            return;

            if(value.Quantity > 1){
                ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption(`${value.Name} (${value.Quantity})`, ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", value]);
            }
            else{
                ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption(`${value.Name}`, ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", value]);
            }
    });
    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.CreateOption("Exit", ["SelectOwnInventoryItem", "exit"]);

    ContextMenu.DrawMenu.Ready(true, cursorpos);
    return;
}
return;
}
```

Comment: prob because splice() is mutating your items array each time it is called, slice() will not - try that

Comment: I see you have in the showNextInventory function `items = invMenuItems`, is this related to the variable of the same name in showPlayerInventory function? Regardless, if you're showing 10 items in `items`, could it be that `invMenuItems` doesn't have those items?

Comment: @danday74 I am wanting to take items out of the array and display those, and then use the `items` array to move onto the next page of items and keep reducing the array till I have none left to display.

@GreyHaven I added it in as a variable at the top of the typescript to see if storing the list each time helped but it didnt.